# Jacking serialize TimeStamp to JSON without @JsonSerialize?

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I currently store in dates as a type `DateTime` but the thing is when I make API calls, I return a `TimeStamp` in my POJO. Since Jackson automatically converts it into milliseconds, I wanted to convert these milliseconds into a `Date` so it is more human-readable. We use RedShift at work ran into some issues trying to serialize the date using `JsonSerialize` because the `serialize` seems to call the wrong `serialize` method to serialize the JSON, causing some errors when trying to store our data into our Postgres SQL. Is there any way to avoid using `JsonSerialize` to serialize the `TimeStamp` to `Date`? Here was my attempt with `JsonSerialize`

HibernateBaseClass.java

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
@Basic(optional=false)
@Column(name="created_on")
private Timestamp createdOn;
```

CustomDateSerializer.java

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Timestamp> {

    private static UserSession userSession = SessionManager.getUserSession();
    public static final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    public static final Locale userLocale = new Locale(userSession.getLocale().toString());
    public static final TimeZone userTimeZone = userSession.getTimeZone();

    @Override
    public void serialize(Timestamp timeStamp, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        if (timeStamp == null) {
            generator.writeNull();
        } else {
            format.setTimeZone(userTimeZone);
            generator.writeString(format.format(timeStamp.getTime()));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Class<Timestamp> handledType() {
        return Timestamp.class;
    }


    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(Timestamp value, JsonGenerator gen,
                              SerializerProvider serializers, TypeSerializer typeSer)
        throws IOException {
        serialize(value, gen, serializers);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean _does something strange_? How does RedShift interfere with Jackson?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it seems that when we try to serialize the `TimeStamp`, it calls the wrong `serialize` method which will cause some errors in how our data is being stored. I have updated my answer to show my attempt in calling the wrong method.